# Boolean Not Rendering in Cycles - Blender 3.4

Tags: boolean-modifier

I have a character setup with the "lighting boy studio" boolean based mouth rig. The booleans visibility is connected via driver to some control bones, but the boolean isn't rendering in cycles. It does render in Eevee however. These meshes arent using toon shading, and I've checked on alot of things like shader settings. Here's a screenshot of my render settings.

Another strange thing is that sometimes when I switch modes, like from edit to pose mode the boolean stops rendering in the viewport and i need to switch to pose mode for it to reappear.

System specs:
Processor: 12th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-12700   2.10 GH
RAM:16GB 3200 MHz DDR4
GPU: NVIDIA® GeForce RTX™ 3060 (LHR); 12 GB

Blend file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1f8SIwBYt0uaI5lh6MLV6_WbdYeioSbOs/view?usp=share_link

[image]
[image]

Answer (score -1):

I think you Disabled Boolean modifier in render

[image]